# How to remove shortcuts of drives from desktop without unmounting it always?

Tags: 12.04, unmount

I have a doubt in UN-mounting the drives in Linux.

**Whenever I open any drives in system its shortcut/image will be shown in the desktop. To remove that I need to right click on it and select unmount.**

Then only that shorcut disappears. This always happens, so whenever I open any drive all of them will be there in desktop. What I need is this shouldn't happen. What can I do for that?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Previously I used 10.10 then also same problem was there.